# PHP SoapClient-exception, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I´ve recently started looking a web service calls using PHP. 
I can´t get the following rather simple snippet to work, instead the web service returns an exception.

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?wsdl");
print($client->__soapCall("GetGeoIP", array('IP' => '83.251.30.62')));
?>
```

I´ve also tried the simpler `$client->GetGeoIP('83.251.30.62');` but they both yield the same result.

Is there something wrong with my code? 
Exception below:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. --->     System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. 
Parameter name: input at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(String input) at 
WebserviceX.Service.Adapter.IPAdapter.CheckIP(String IP) at 
WebserviceX.Service.GeoIPService.GetGeoIP(String IPAddress) --- End of inner exception 
stack trace --- in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software 
Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\isolda\test.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\isolda\test.php(16): SoapClient-
>__soapCall('GetGeoIP', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache 
Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\isolda\test.php on line 16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write `"IPAddress"` instead of `'IP'` (Inside the array) and it will work.

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?wsdl"); 

$result = $client->GetGeoIP(array("IPAddress" => "83.251.30.62")); //change was made here

echo $result->GetGeoIPResult->CountryName;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it still yields the same exception :(

Comment: Oh, it does. I tried changing my code above with __soapCall to use IPAddress, that is what isn´t working. Wierd, what´s the difference anyway?

Comment: The web service is looking for a string variable named `"IPAddress"` and not `"IP"`, thats all. I suggest using [Membrance Soap Client](http://www.membrane-soa.org/soap-client/), It can be used to easily see the names of the input variables.

Comment: Thanks alot! Marked as answer